# How to access variables in postback?

Tags: asp.net

how do I access variables in a simple asp.net postback using either POST or GET?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With parameters passed in the query string, you use Request.QueryString[], and with parameters that are POSTed, you use Request.Form[].

Answer (score 3):

`string myValue = Request["Field_name"];`